# Dymanic PickList Applet is empty Siebel

Tags: siebel, picklist

Can you help me, please?

I've created a dynamic PickList and Pick Applet, but when it's displayed there is no records. I've created all joins (I join with S_CONTACT on ROW_ID to take Last and First names), pick map an specified my PickList to the field. I think i missed link between PickList and Pick Applet, but i'm not sure and i don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was in defining Business Component: i was looking throught the same on for field and picklist.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Siebel, may I point out that Siebel tools has some wizards which can make things easier. To add a dynamic picklist on a field, right click on the field in Siebel tools, and choose 'Add Picklist'. Then follow the onscreen instructions, which will also help configure a pick applet. Try re-creating the dynamic picklist using this wizard.

If you do not want to try this, you will have to spool the sql logs to get sql which could point to the issue. It could be a searhspec issue on the picklist/picklist bus comp/pick applet. It could even be a buscomp visibility issue (salesrep, org). Also check the pop-up visibility for the buscomps, and see if there are any other constrains on the pickmap.

Comment: Can you, please, advise me some materials, books to read about siebel? I'm just starting and sometimes make some stupid mistakes, and manuals are often not enought